# Bounding an expression.

Tags: calculus

I am dealing with the following expression :

$27*\left | x-2 \right |*\frac{1}{\left | 2x - 5 \right |}$

I need to show that $27*\left | x-2 \right |*\frac{1}{\left | 2x - 5 \right |} < \varepsilon\; $ for a certain $0<\left | x - 2 \right | < \delta $

Therefore I need to bound $\;\frac{1}{\left | 2x - 5 \right |}$ from below in order for $\varepsilon$ to not be really big,

Lets say i'll take $\delta = 0.25$ then :

$1.75 < x < 2.25$

$3.5 < 2x < 4.5$

$3.5 < 2x - 5 < 4.5$

$0.5 < \left |2x - 5  \right | < 1.5$

$2 > \frac{1}{\left | 2x - 5 \right |} > \frac{2}{3}$

Is this move legal?

Comment: If $3.5<2x<4.5$ then $-1.5<2x-5<-0.5$

Comment: @Tanner, isn't it problematic that it is a negative number? How should I handle it properly?

Comment: Try computing the range of $|2x -5|$ for a general $\delta$ and then plugin the minimum value of that into the main equation and see if you can find a relation for $\epsilon$.

Comment: When you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, reverse the inequality

Answer (score 1):

Your moves are legal, but I think you meant $-1.5<2x-5<-0.5$ when you wrote $3.5<2x-5<4.5$.

Here is the justification:

$1.75 < x < 2.25\quad$ (assumption)

$3.5 < 2x < 4.5\quad$  (multiply by $2$)

$-1.5 < 2x - 5 < -0.5\quad$  (subtract $5$)

$0.5 < \left |2x - 5  \right | < 1.5\quad$  (multiply by $-1$, so reverse the inequality)

$\dfrac 1 {|2x-5|}<2\quad$   (multiply by $\dfrac2{\left | 2x - 5 \right |}$)

and  $\dfrac23<\dfrac1{\left | 2x - 5 \right |}\quad$  (multiply by $\dfrac2{3\left | 2x - 5 \right |})$

therefore $2 > \dfrac{1}{\left | 2x - 5 \right |} > \dfrac{2}{3}.$